# LINQ with multiple selection and group by multiple selection

Tags: c#, linq

i have a table like this:

```
First Field | Second Field |  Third Field   |   Fourth Field
------------+--------------+----------------+----------------
 5      |     aaaa     |      47            |       abc
 5      |     aaaa     |      57            |       def
 5      |     aaaa     |      63            |       xyz
 5      |     bbbb     |      39            |       www
 5      |     bbbb     |      37            |       lol
 5      |     cccc     |      84            |       yuy
```

I want to group this table by first and the second field, but i want to get only the rows with the biggest third fields.

How can i do this via LINQ in c#?

```
var curi = (from row in customClassList.AsEnumerable()
                    group row by new
                    {
                        First = row.FirstField.ToString(),
                        Second = row.SecondSield.ToString(),
                    } into grp
                    select new FieldsClass
                    {
                        First = grp.Key.First,
                        Second = grp.Key.Second,
                        Third = grp.Select(p => p.ThirdField).Max().ToShort(),
                        Fourth = grp.Key.Fourth
                    }).ToList();
```

This is my expected result:

```
First Field | Second Field |  Third Field   |   Fourth Field
------------+--------------+----------------+----------------
 5      |     aaaa     |      63            |       xyz
 5      |     bbbb     |      39            |       www
 5      |     cccc     |      84            |       yuy
```

Comment: So what happens with the code you have? Something? Nothing? Errors?

Comment: what exactly is your expected result?

Comment: I tried a lot of queries but i cant get what i want. I think this code is the nearest code but it is not building, i cant try it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about

```
var result = customClassList.GroupBy(x => new {x.FirstField, x.SecondField})
                            .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.ThirdField).First());
```

Comment: Exactly :) Thanks @fubo